# When using the State pattern, are time consuming transitions really just states?

Tags: design-patterns, state, transition, state-pattern

I am using the State Pattern to design a service to control a physical machine.  The machine has Open and Closed states (along with a few other useful states).  Additionally, it has transitions like Open ==> Close.

These transitions start physical processes that take time, and I'm wondering if I really should should model them as States.

On the one hand, these are not stable states that I expect the machine to be in.  They don't have multiple behaviors, and they don't accept commands.  Opening, does just one thing - it transitions to Open.

On the other hand, I want people to be able to query the service and get a real answer about what its state is.  If a process requests my state and I have sent the Open command to the machine, but it has not finished Opening, then what should I return for a state? Opening sounds right.

Advice? Wisdom? Are there trade offs between the two approaches?

Comment: You need to have stable states while implementing state machine. For e.g in this case you should have four states : Open, Opening, Closed and Closing. This will make your state machine more clear.Also the transition of state machine is generally based on an event i.e when the state machine changes from Closed to Opening there is an event, and when the state changes from Opening to Open there is an event. It doesn't matters how much time your code takes to generate the event, the state machine is only interested to maintain the state.